# Trying to run php file in cmd, without using xampp, however it's not working

Tags: php

I run the directory folder of the code that I'm about to run, then I used the code `php -S localhost:3000`, I also tried `php -S localhost:8000` and `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080`, however none of these codes seems to work.

```
C:\Users\Documents\fisiko\v2-boston-brain-science> php -S localhost:3000
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file
```

why is this happening??

Comment: You have to install PHP or XAMPP to use PHP. It's not native. Have a look on https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/

Comment: I've found the solution, but thanks for your response, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this issue has happened to me in the past, is most likely because of php is not been recognized by Windows. I've had to add manually the path to where is PHP `C:\xampp\php` to the system properties, not sure if this was already added.

[image]

Restart your machine, the new value should be loaded in the variable Path in the system. Now php should be recognizable. Typing `php -v` in the console should be return something like:

```
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:24:02) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Should be good after, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks so much, I've tried what you've instructed and it worked, you're a great help!!!

Comment: @Mirwell I'm glad it worked, thanks for the feedback :)